# Tkinter: Output widget isn't displaying text

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, output

I'm relatively new when it comes to python and even more new when it comes to Tkinter, and I am making a Dice game program using GUIs and functions. At the end of the game, a new window pops up and displays some text with an output Widget that is meant to display the score, however, it doesn't appear. I believe I am using the right syntax, and there are no error messages when I run the program. Any answer would be appreciated.

Here is my code below:

'''

```
# SPICEY DICE Code snippet.
# - Create window
window2 = Tk()
window2.title("SPICEY DICE - Single Player Finish")
# - Label 1
Label(window2, text = "CONGRATULATIONS!").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
# - Label 2
Label(window2, text = "You have finished SPICEY DICE with a score of:").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
# - Text box 1
Output5 = Text(window2, width = 5, height = 1, wrap = WORD, background = "yellow")
Output5.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
# - Button 1
Button(window2, text = "LEADERBOARD", width = 15, command = SPLeaderboard).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
# - Label 3
Label(window2, text = "Close all of the windows to finish.").grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
# - Run mainloop
window2.mainloop()

Output5.delete(0.0, END)
Output5.insert(END, str(TotalScore))
```

'''

The Output widget in question is 'Output5' and 'TotalScore' is the variable that is meant to be printed into it but doesn't appear.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to write:

```
Output5.delete(0.0, END)
Output5.insert(END, str(TotalScore))
```

these codes between `Tk()` and `mainloop`.